# Using Juju returns "ssh invalid key" error

Tags: ssh, juju

Can someone tell me with piece of code is executed when i do: `juju status`.

I'm running Juju on OpenStack and I want to deploy some services but when i do juju status it returns me an SSH INVALID KEY error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
ConnectionReset reading response for 'BzrDir.open_2.1', retrying
Permission denied (publickey).
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.
```

Comment: I Still seem to have the same Error although i can ssh successfully onto the other machine and back but while trying the command 'juju status' i always seem to get the error invalid ssh key or the machine may still be initializing. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to generate a keypair on machine from which you're running `juju bootstrap`.

I just generated the keyspair

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

Again did,

```
juju -v bootstrap
```

You should also integrate your ssh key with Launchpad so that you can pull charms from the charm store:

- https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/CreatingAnSSHKeyPair

Answer (score 2):

Given that juju verifies at bootstrap that it has a valid ssh key. I think the problem more likely related to the image, namely that it doesn't have a cloud-init installed in the image. Juju needs cloud-init installed in the image to finish the instance installation post launch. ie. a standard server iso image is not sufficient, it needs to have cloud-init installed. Standard cloud images which have cloud-init can be found here

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/server/

If error persists please pastebin the output from

```
euca-get-console-output instance-id
```

Comment: I think it has more to do with my network connection because my Nova does not direct internet access, the routing fails when the running instance tires to install zookeeper and other packages. Please find output of `euca-get-console-output instance-id` along with http://paste.ubuntu.com/753480/